# Node.js callbacks in module are never called

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, callback

**My problem actually is that I was using the response body before the callback was called, which resulted in an error and therefore the callback was never called.**

I am using [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request), though this problem seems to happen with any callback.

If I do something like this.

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports.test = function ()
{
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        /**
         * This callback doesn't seem to ever be called.
         */

        console.log(body);
    });
};
```

And use it like.

```
var mytest = require('./test.js');

mytest.test();
```

The callback doesn't seem to ever be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as expected and if you don't see any output that means some error had place which should be indicated in `error` argument passed to your function.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  } else {
    console.log('error: '+ response.statusCode)
  }
});
```